# Using python to convert wav file to csv file before feed the data into FFT for audio spectrum analyzer

Tags: python, audio, fpga, analyzer, spectrum

I am working on a simple audio spectrum analyzer using FPGA. For the preprocessing part, my idea is to use python to convert wav file to csv file, and then feed the data to a fast fourier transform module. Is it possible to get it work?

Comment: You could also simply using scipy.io to open the wave file in python and get a numpy array. Then you could use either scipy FFT or numpy FFT module. No need to use a CSV (slow) in between.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of available open source modules to perform this:
A [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Lukious/wav-to-csv) for same.

Just open github and type wav to csv and you'll find quite a lot of them.
Or even google a bit and you can find lot of answers on same.

One small query though. You basically want to convert the .wav file into a time series data right?

In that case, I'll highly recommend to go through:
[KDNugget's](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/02/audio-data-analysis-deep-learning-python-part-1.html) post about same.